# Статические файлы на tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Есть REST сервер который в json отдает информацию о профайлах на android.
Задача в том как сделать так чтобы фото для профайлов грузились с сервера из отдельно стоящей директории по переданным для них url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке `webapps` создайте папку для хранения файлов, например, `downloads` и в ней храните файлы, которые требуется скачивать. Файлы будут доступны по URL `{адрес-сервера}/downloads/имя-файла`. Этот URL следует отдавать в REST-сервисе, клиент должен будет скачивать фото отдельным запросом, уже после получения ответа от REST-сервиса.

Comment: Сделал.  (localhost:8080/downloads/11.png) но ответ 404.

Comment: Должно работать, я проверял. Убедитесь в том, что есть такой путь в файловой системе: webapps/downloads/11.png. Возможно, что-то в конфигурации сервера или приложения приводит к ошибке. Попробуйте развернуть "чистый" Tomcat из дистрибутива, создать в webapps любую папку и сохранить в ней любой файл. Запускайте Tomcat как самостоятельное приложение, а не под управлением среды разработки.

Comment: Запустил Tomcat из консоли - работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Корневая папка в томкате webapps/ROOT. То есть папка webapps/ROOT/downloads на сервере видна как localhost:8080/downloads.